# Regex remove comments but not shebang

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I got a regex that removes the comments in bash using this regex code

```
'/^\#/d'
```

but it also removes the #! which should be not because it's not a comment tag but a shebang

so how can it be done to ignore #! in regex?

Comment: Have you tried `'/^\#^[!]/d'/`? Sorry, I can't try myself now...

Comment: Which regex flavor are you working with?

Comment: what do you mean by flavor?

Comment: @Axel it won't remove any comments at all

Comment: Yes, I misplaced the `^`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will remove every comment starting with # but is not followed by an !.

```
'/^#[^!]/d'
```

Comment: I already got it but i'll just make yours as the correct answer since you also got it.

Comment: This will not remove empty comment lines e.g. lines with just a single `#`.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the `!` optional

```
'/^#[^!]*/d'
```

Comment: I got it. just remove the * on it and it will work fine. so it should be  '/^#[^!]/d'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/^$/ || (NR == 1 && /^#!/) || /^[^#]/'
```

This matches lines that:

- are empty, OR
- are the first line and start with hashbang, OR
- start with a character that is not a hash.

Matched lines are printed out.

Answer (score 0):

`^\#[^!]` isn't quite right, because it demands any non-`!` character after the `#`, so it won't remove lines which are just `#` with nothing after it. I don't know what flavor of regex you're using, so the syntax may differ, but you're looking for [negative forward lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `^#(?!!)`. Also, the `#` character doesn't need to be escaped with `\` at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
/^(#[^!]|#$)/d
```

where `|#$` is the addition to match a single hash line special case. E.g:

```
cat commented.sh | sed '/^\(#[^!]\|#$\)/d'
```

Comment: didn't you forget the `.*` after the `]` ? I use `sed -i '/^\s*\(#[^!].*\|#$\)/d' commented.sh`